# USB Serial Communication for STM32F401C-Discovery using Keil uVision5

Tags: usb, serial, stm32f4

I have developed a STM32f401c-disco board using Keil, and next I would want to be able to send data out (say just a "hello" string) via the serial link USB-ed back to my PC and show it (I have Hercules Utility installed in my PC).

I know that I'll have to do some setting up before I can do that, but I am not sure how to go about it, been struggling, can anyone help?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to use Keil's USB stack, you'll need a paid up licence.  If you have a licence then I suggest you start by modifying one of their example STM32 USB-serial projects.

If you don't have a paid-for Keil licence, I wouldn't use the free "eval" licence.  Try the [CooCox IDE](http://www.coocox.org/index.html), and have a look at [Uwe Becker's STM32F4 Discovery USB-serial example project](http://mikrocontroller.bplaced.net/wordpress/?page_id=1974) (It's in German, but the Google translation is pretty reasonable).

Comment: If you don't want to buy a license (which can be as much about future-proofing your development setup as about cost), then don't use a demo version of a fee-for-license toolchain (and just get yourself in a future bind), instead use one of the free gcc based toolchains.

Comment: Is there a way where I can actually download a USB VCP driver?

Comment: @LCS I'm not clear whether you mean a driver to run on the STM32 or on a PC.  If the latter then yes, if the former then no, you'd need to write one afaik.

Comment: @markt I've actually downloaded a driver setup exe for the PC, but I guess it is not compatible on Windows 8, so it didn't work.